# Vue.js/Inertia wait for all sync setups before render

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I am generating my navigation menu server side and rendering it on the client side using async setups and the suspense API. Since Inertia gives me this information every page load, this means that every time I change page the navigation has to render again and flickers due to the async setups and suspense.

Is there a way to wait for all async setups before discarding the previous page and rendering the new page? Like a full-vue suspense.

Comment: Does the menu change often? If not, you are probably better of caching it. If you think async looks bad because of a small flickering, wait untill you tried the sync option and realize you are now staring at a blank page untill everything is done.

Comment: @RobBiermann Apparently that is against the idea of Inertia so I wanted to find another solution before I tried that. I'm looking for an option that waits for the next page to be ready before blanking the page, if that is possible at all.

Comment: I get what you mean, it would be nice to seamlessly load a page. The problem is that you are just moving the waiting time from after the page reload to before the page reload(if it is possible at all). It's gonna feel laggy nontheless. What you should want is no waiting time, imo.

Comment: @RobBiermann I do agree with that so I'm leaning towards only passing the menu on first page load and only doing client side changes afterwards. I would just like to explore my options as the Inertia devs stated here: https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/issues/134 That this conflicts with their design for Inertia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with the option suggested by @RobBiermann

Using the method described in https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/issues/134#issuecomment-966387241:

> On HandleInertiaRequests middleware:
>
> ```
> public function share(Request $request): array
> {
>     $firstLoadOnlyProps = $request->inertia() ? [] : [
>         'translations' => // your logic here
>     ];
>
>     return array_merge(parent::share($request), $firstLoadOnlyProps, [
>         'yourNormalAlwaysSharedProps' => fn () => // your logic
>     ];
> }
> ```

And persistent layouts https://inertiajs.com/pages#persistent-layouts.

It is possible to load components once and keep them until reload. This prevents the flicker I experienced when switching between pages.